# Punctuation after "I couldn't help but to think" introducing a quote — colon or comma?

Tags: punctuation, commas, colons

> I couldn’t help but to think: “Is this really what the meaning of success has become?” and to make matters even worse, this idea was just spread to the thousands of viewers.

Is the colon correct? I am unsure about using a colon versus a comma.

Comment: You shouldn't be worrying about punctuation decisions until you get the grammar and lexical decisions made correctly. For instance, the idiom is _couldn't help but think_ (no _to_); and it's _thousands of viewers_ (no _the_). And why use passive causative _was spread_ when intransitive _spread_ works all by itself? Punctuation is frosting; bake the cake before you frost it.

Comment: @John: I think the idiom is actually *I couldn't but think* or *I couldn't help thinking*.

Comment: To answer your actual question, the colon is fine. @John: *was spread* and *spread* have slightly different connotations here, and you'd have to decide from context (which we don't have) which is better.

Comment: @TimLymington. _Couldn’t help but_ is certainly found, as in this OED citation from 1999: ‘I didn't understand half of what was going on, but I couldn't help but notice that the procedure was incredibly baroque’.

Comment: @TimLymington: The OP's idiom had _help_ and an infinitive with _to_. The _to_ is incorrect in **all** these idioms: *I couldn't but to think; I couldn't help but to notice; I couldn't help to noticing.*

Comment: Off topic: request for writing advice/critique.

Answer (score 2):

I say that the colon is not at all necessary, as the quoted phrase is simply the object of the sentence particle before it; a comma is a much more natural pause there.  My version would be:

> I couldn't help but think, "Is this really what the meaning of success has become?"  And to make matters even worse, the idea was just spread to thousands of viewers.

The "make matters worse" part needs to be its own sentence because it's not part of what you "couldn't help but" do.

Also as pointed out by @John Lawler, you can see that I've used "couldn't help but think" without the *to* and "thousands of viewers" without "the".

I think that "was spread" is appropriate, because all we know at this point is that the idea has been sent out; we don't know if it was then taken in by the people to whom it was broadcast, which would be necessary for "spread".

Comment: -1 for last paragraph

Comment: @jwpat7, You don't think there's a difference between "the idea spread to thousands of people" and "the idea was spread to thousands of people"?  It seems quite clear to me.

Comment: You are probably right.

Answer (score -1):

If the first clause is independent, you should use a colon. If, as in your example, then either a colon or a comma is grammatically correct.

Stylistically, the colon emphasizes the quotation somewhat more than the comma.

Lists should be preceded by a colon. I have heard (sorry, I don't remember where) a rule of thumb that one should use a comma before shorter quotations (10 words or less), a colon before longer quotations.

Comment: Just because I always seek to get better, I'd love whoever downvoted my answer to let me know why!